# How to access Spark web UI in Yarn mode

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I am running a pyspark job as a AWS EMR step and the script takes well over 15 minutes to run. I have 1 master and 3 core nodes in the EMR cluster. I want to find out why and which part of my script is taking long. For that I wanted to see the Spark web UI. When I click on "Tracking URL: Applicationmaster" in Yarn UI (port 8088), my browser keeps spinning and it unable to display the Spark UI. The URL link in the browser is:

```
http://ip-172-31-x-x.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1579701541309_1029/
```

This is obviously private DNS. How do I see the Spark UI even if this is on a temporary basis for me to troubleshoot. I can change the AWS Security group, if needed. And later, how can this be handled when I am in production environment?

Thanks

Comment: security group?

Comment: What YARN is reporting is **not** the UI of the Spark driver -- it's the status page of the YARN container running the "YARN Application Master" for the executors.

Comment: If you want to investigate after the job has ended, then you need to set up Spark HistoryServer and configure the Spark jobs to dump their JSON report inside the HDFS dir used by HS. You can even inspect running jobs with HS, except that you won't see anything about the currently running step, and you are bound by the refresh rate of HS service.

Comment: If you want to use the UI of the running job, then use `yarn-client` mode and **look into the driver logs** to get the actual URL (port 4040 by default but if already taken, will use 4041 etc)

Comment: And... spend a few hours reading some Spark documentation. Might improve your score in here.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter. Thanks. I have been doing extensive reading in "Spark in Action" book and some articles on net. The confusion it causes is some articles relate to home built HDFS/Spark clusters and some are AWS EMR based and things are very different in the two. And since I am self-learning, sometimes I am going round in circles.So, I know YARN is not reporting Spark driver info. I want to see the Spark driver info which I was able to see when using Spark Standalone CM. When I do the same with port 4040 and Yarn, it doesn't work.

Comment: _"with port 4040 and Yarn"_ > I don't understand what you mean. The Spark driver uses port 4040+ for its UI, when configured to do so (enabled by default, range 4040-4056 available by default) but YARN is not aware of that. The point of using **client** mode is that you know on which machine the driver runs.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter. I figured out the problem. Sorry about all the confusion. Used SSH tunneling using Foxyproxy to view the Spark UI. Thanks